# css style that fixes list item alignment

Tags: css

In the screenshot below - is there a css style that would align the 'Administration and roles' text with the 'Plan registration number' text?  I've tried list-style-position: outside and list-style-position: inside and it makes no difference.

[image]

Comment: If you're gonna downvote - you should have to comment as to why.  I have no idea how this question offended some stackoverflow vigilante.

Comment: Does this help you: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-position

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a CSS counter.
That way you can customise the numbering format or style more easily

Check out this [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters)

I have created a quick [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ub8nwf12/1/) to demonstrate.

```
ol {
    counter-reset: section;                
    list-style-type: none;
}
ol li:before {
    counter-increment: section;            
    content: counters(section,".") ". ";
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: right;
    min-width: 36px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```